# Pre-hide separately button and image as button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a code that prints out several buttons, depending on how many "answers" there are on my page. However, I want the buttons to have the function that should show a text that belongs to each answer when I press the button.

The problem is that the text for every answer is already showed when I enter the site, I want it to be hidden and showed when I click on the button. The problem is also that every button is getting toggled when I press any of them, I want every to be separately. AND I have an image that I want to use as a button and be able to click on the image, but since I haven't managed to fix it I use the image inside a button. I have searched on many sites for help but I don't manage to do it...

Do I maybe miss some CSS, among other missing code?

```css
<style>
.question-wrap{margin-bottom: 2em}
p.answer{display: none}
</style>
```

```js
<script>
$("button.answer-toggle").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.question-wrap').find('.answer').toggle();
    // Tested with the one above and below at the same time and then one at a time.
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
</script>
```

```html
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<div class='question-wrap'><b><small>Dilemma ".$row['qid']." - Answer ". $row['aid'].":</small></b> ". $row['points']." of 10 <b><small>points</small></b>
    <button class='answer-toggle'><input type='image' title='Information' src='img/down.png' width='13' height='10'></button>
    <p class='answer'>Answer text.</p></div>
    <br>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters it is generally best to wrap repeating modules  in their own containers. This helps  lot for instance specific traversals and for css

```
<div class="question-wrap">
   <button class="answer-toggle"></button>
   <p class="answer"></p>
</div>
```

Then for the click handler you have several different traverses available to isolate instance specific elements.

```
$("button.answer-toggle").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.question-wrap').find('.answer').toggle();
    // OR
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

CSS

```
.question-wrap{margin-bottom: 2em}
p.answer{display: none}
```

Comment: The answer-text is now pre-hidden but nothing shows up when I press any button. I was not sure what you ment with the two lines between //OR, so I triend with both of them at the same time and then with one at a time. Same result.

Comment: Why? What is the point of this answer if you incorporate it into the question? Now the answer seems pointless as it's nothing more than a duplicate of the question

Comment: I want to show a text below the button after I click on it, but it is always hidden now and doesn't toggle.

Comment: But as I can see, there is no document.ready? And can you tell me if you ment that I should use both the lines between the "//OR", or just one of them?

Comment: No..one or the other and put it inside the `ready` handler you had in question originally

Comment: Nice, I got it to work. Can you just tell me now how I can have the same thing and functions, but without a <button>? I want to make the image inside the button to be alone and to work as a button, so I can click on the image instead? I tried now to put the class='answer-toggle' inside the image and remove the <button> but it didn't work.

Comment: remove `button` from the selector, just use the class

Comment: Do you mean like this <class='answer-toggle'><input type='image' title='Information' src='img/down.png' width='13' height='10'><p class='answer'>Answer text.</p>

Comment: No...the jQuery selector. That's not valid html. Suggest you study some basics on jQuery selectors

Comment: Should I remove or keep the dot after I remove the button from button.answer-toggle, the dot between button and answer-toggle

Comment: I removed the the button from button.answer-toggle and kept <button class='answer-toggle'>. The button still looks the same with a image inside the button, I just want the image and make it work as a button

Comment: So put the class on image and use class selector  only for jQuery

Comment: Another question, if you would like to help me. There is space much space between the question rows, I suppose that it's because the answers are hidden between them. Is it possible to not have any space between the question-texts and after I press the image, to show the answer as is already does?

Comment: That is all in the css. Adjust to suit. If needed toggle a class on the container when button is clicked